# Run single test to check code coverage Jacoco Android

Tags: android, jacoco

I'm using `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` to generate a code coverage report of all my Android instrumentation (Robotium) tests. But I need to run all tests in order to get the coverage report now. How can I specify one single test (or single test class) to execute and get the coverage report? I beed it during development of the tests, it's too slow having to run all tests at once.

Comment: simply exclude the classes?

Comment: You can do it from AndroidStudio just define one class run.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but here's how I do it.

#### 1. First install the instrumentation test app if you have not.

(Flavor may vary. In this case, it's `debug`.)

```sh
// install instrumentation test app if you have not
./gradlew installDebugAndroidTest
```

#### 2. Execute a test you want (or tests, classes, packages ..).

In my case, I chose `ClassName#methodName`.

```sh
// execute one test
adb shell am instrument -w -r --no_window_animation -e coverageFile /data/data/com.org.android.test/coverage.ec -e class 'com.org.android.ClassName#methodName', -e coverage true com.org.android.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Note that I'm passing 2 parameters:

A. `-e coverageFile /data/data/com.org.android.test/coverage.ec` and,

B. `-e coverage true`

The two options would generate a coverage report within the device.

If you are not familiar with running tests by `adb shell am` command, please refer to [this official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#AMSyntax).

#### 3. Then get the coverage.ec file from the device.

```sh
// get coverage.ec data
adb shell run-as com.org.android.test  cat /data/data/com.org.android.test/coverage.ec | cat > [YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY]/build/outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/coverage.exec
```

There are two things to note here.

A. You should change `[YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY]` to your project directory. Or, you can change the entire `[YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY]/build/outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/coverage.exec` to any directory and filename you want. (maybe desktop?)

B. but the final content should have extension `.exec`, because jacoco will only accept those.

#### 4. Then view the coverage report using Android Studio.

In Android Studio, please navigate to `run` > `Show Code Coverage Data`. Then a select window will appear. Select previously generated `coverage.exec`. Then the Android Studio will process the data and show you the coverage data. You can directly view the code coverage data, or further generate coverage report.